# I do have a list of dictionaries and I am interested in getting values of only select key

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, lis

I have used this code on my dataframe of sql queries to obtain list of dictionaries that has select, where, join columns:

```
def augment(x):
    try:
        return Parser(x).columns_dict
    except:
        pass

df_1_joins_where= df_1['SQL_TEXT'].apply(lambda x: augment(x))
```

I get a list of dictionary like this:

```
 {'select': ['all_cons_columns.column_name'], '...
1              {'select': ['free_mb'], 'where': ['name']}
2       {'select': ['all_cons_columns.column_name'], '...
3       {'select': ['all_cons_columns.column_name'], '...
4       {'select': ['AA.BB.CC_...
                              ...                        
4995    {'select': ['AA.BB.CC...
4996    {'select': ['AA.BB.CC_...
4997    {'select': ['AA.BB.CC_...
4998    {'select': ['AA.BB.CC_...
4999                                    {'select': ['*']}
```

Single dictionary in my list could look like this:

```
{'select': ['Names'], 'where': ['point']}
```

or could have just select key or:

```
{'select': ['Table.ColumnA']]}
```

or it could have all three (select, where, join) keys as well

I want to extract all the values paired with where key, how could I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you a `list` of all values across all `dict`s that have the `"where"` key:

```
dict_list = df_1_joins_where= df_1['SQL_TEXT'].apply(lambda x: augment(x))

all_where_values = []
for d in dict_list:
    if 'where' in d:
         all_where_values += [d["where"]]
```

Note that, since in general the value of keys `"where"` is a `list`, `all_where_values` with be a `list` of `list`s.